# Reduction of polynomials

Tags: polynomials

Question:

The polynomial $x^{2k} + 1 + (x+1)^{2k}$ is not divisible by $x^2-x-1$.Find value of natural $k$.

My soln :

By reducing the polynomial as $x^2= x+1$ .

I got the polynomial as $x^{4k} + x^{2k} + 1$.

Now,I stuck here and now couldn't get the answer.

Plz guide me how to solve the problem

Comment: Hi, I have edited your post and converted it to [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Please check if this has been done correctly. (Also, please use Mathjax next time.)

Comment: Also, I think you are nearly there. $x^2-x-1$ has two real roots, and if the original polynomial was divisible by $x^2-x-1$ those would be roots of it, and therefore also of $x^{4k}+x^{2k}+1$. However, the latter has no real roots.

Comment: Alright i got (1+ root 5)/2 and (1-root5)/2 as it roots,I got [(7+ root 3)/2 ] power k + [(3+ rooot 5)/2] power k + 1 as the value of polynomial of x

Comment: Did you know that you can use MathJax in comments as well?

Comment: NOw what do I do?

Comment: $x^{4k}+x^{2k}+1$ has no real roots because $x^{4k}+x^{2k}+1\ge 1$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$ (notice that the terms $x^{4k}$ and $x^{2k}$ are both squares, therefore non-negative).

Answer (score 3):

Let $x^{2k} + 1 + (x+1)^{2k}$ is divisible by $x^2-x-1$ $\Leftrightarrow$

$x^{2k} + 1 + (x+1)^{2k} = (x^2-x-1)P(x)$

Let $a$ is the root of $x^2-x-1$ ($a$ is real). So, $a^2 = a+1$. Put it into equation above:

$a^{2k} + 1 + (a^2)^{2k} = 0$ $\Leftrightarrow$

$a^{4k} + a^{2k} + 1 = 0$ $\Leftrightarrow$

$(a^{4k} + 2\cdot a^{2k} + 1) - a^{2k} = 0$ $\Leftrightarrow$

$(a^{2k} + 1 - a^k)(a^{2k} + 1 + a^k) = 0$

But both $a^{2k} + 1 - a^k = 0$ and $a^{2k} + 1 + a^k = 0$ have no real roots for all $k$ (substitution $a^k$).

So, for all positive integers $k$ $x^{2k} + 1 + (x+1)^{2k}$ is not divisible by $x^2-x-1$.

Comment: You are working a bit harder than you need to: if $p_k(x)=x^{2k}+1+(x+1)^{2k}$ is divisible by $x^2-x-1$, then both real roots of $x^2-x-1$ will be roots of $p_k(x)$ as you say, and moreover if $a$ is such a root $a^2=a+1$ so that $0=p_k(a) =a^{4k}+a^{2k}+1 = (a^{2k})^2+(a^k)^2+1\geq 1$, hence we have a contradiction.

Comment: Sir, by this soln how we are gonna know that there is no real root for the polynomials at any k.

Sir did u by any change used edl to proove this?

Comment: @ReferencePoint We consider some $k$ for which polynomial is divisible by $x^2-x-1$ and got a contradiction. So, for all $k$ it is not divisible.

Comment: really couldnt understand how u got a contradiction

Comment: @ReferencePoint On the one side $a$ is real (because both roots of $x^2-x-1=0$ are real), on the other side $a$ is not real (because $x^{4k} + x^{2k} + 1 = 0$ has no real roots, but $a$ is the root of this equation also)

Comment: alright got it thanks